# PluralizationServices changing Status to Statu

Tags: c#, pluralize

We have a T4 template using `System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices` to handle table names for some model generation.

When we run a table with `Status` in the name, such as `CompanyStatus`, the `Singularize` method returns `CompanyStatu`. I have some sample code below.

How can I get it to see CompanyStatus correctly?

```
void Main()
{
    // Sanity checks
    Console.WriteLine(Singularize("Cats"));
    Console.WriteLine(Singularize("Cat"));
    Console.WriteLine(Singularize("Status"));
    // The real issue
    Console.WriteLine(Singularize("CompanyStatus"));
}

static string Singularize(string word)
{
    var singularword = System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices.PluralizationService.CreateService(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us")).Singularize(word);
    return singularword;
}
```

This returns:

> Cat
>   Cat
>   Status
>   CompanyStatu

I also tried:

```
static string Singularize(string word)
{
    var pluralizationService = System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices.PluralizationService.CreateService(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"));
    ((ICustomPluralizationMapping)pluralizationService).AddWord("companystatus", "companystatuses");
    var singularword = pluralizationService.Singularize(word);      
    return singularword;
}
```

Comment: Maybe `((ICustomPluralizationMapping)pluralizationService).AddWord("companystatus", "companystatus");`

Comment: Still no @Kevorkian.

Answer (score 1):

[Humanizer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Humanizer) will do this out-of-the box if that's an option?

```
// Note that you have to set the "inputIsKnownToBePlural" flag to false,
// or it will behave the same as PluralizationServices.

Console.WriteLine("Statuses".Singularize(inputIsKnownToBePlural: false));
Console.WriteLine("Status".Singularize(inputIsKnownToBePlural: false));
Console.WriteLine("CompanyStatus".Singularize(inputIsKnownToBePlural: false));
Console.WriteLine("CompanyStatuses".Singularize(inputIsKnownToBePlural: false));
```

[Documentation](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer#singularize).