# Is there a bug in C#'s PluralizationService, or am I not setting something up properly?

Tags: c#, string

I don't do any special setup other than the standard initialization of the `PluralizationService`.

````
PluralizationService ps = PluralizationService.CreateService(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"));

    // they may have said pigS, so we will singularize it
    if (ps.IsPlural(temp_word))
        temp_word = ps.Singularize(temp_word);```
````

My program allows players in my game to search for animals. When they search for `goats` or `sheep` or `pigs` the system works fine. the ps.Singularize function works correctly in all cases. (object classes are `pig` not `pigs`, `sheep`, and `goat` not `goats`.)

The fun starts when someone searches for `horses`. The `ps.Singularize` function returns `hors`.
Is there some sort of rule I forgot to initialize or something or is this a straight-up bug.

I really don't want to have to special case each singularization failure.

Comment: Looks like it's just not very good. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41448588/pluralizationservices-changing-status-to-statu

Comment: Bear in mind the namespace of the type. It's vast majority of usage is for supplying *default* guesses for plurals/singulars, in a situation where *the developer can override it if it gets the guess wrong*.

Comment: You could try if https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pluralize.NET.Core/ works better instead. PS despite the "Core" package name, the page says it's compatible with [.NET Standard 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your tips and insights.
I think I have found the answer, (although I would have preferred that function just work with common English words.)
The solution is here:

> A word about ICustomPluralizationMapping We can however, create our
> own singular and plural words. For that reason, we need the help of
> "ICustomPluralizationMapping" interface. It represents a collection of
> the singular and plural forms of words.
>
> It has only one method
>
> void AddWord(string singular, string plural) The method adds singular
> and plural forms of a word to the
> System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices.ICustomPluralizationMapping
> object.
> https://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2260/let-us-learn-pluralizationservices-of-net-40

So I can add any words that otherwise messup to the dictionary and not ugly-up my code with a bunch of special cases.